# dynamically change name attribute on select box jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically change the "name" attribute on each select box. Here's my scenario: User clicks on first select box option, depending on what the user selected, a new select box appears with the remaining options in it.  User can do this up to 4 times - meaning in total, 4 select boxes can be displayed with first select box containing all options, second select box obtaining 1 less option, and so forth.  This I have accomplished with some help from others here on stackoverflow.  However, aside from all that, I also have this information of what the user selects for each select box phpmailed to my email account and for this to work, I need to use the "name" attribute on each select box.  So my question at hand is, how can I get this to work where each select box that appears has its name attribute dynamically changed (ex: name="guest_al-2" where 2 would change to 3 and so forth once a new select box is dynamically created).

Here is what I got so far.  [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zz1tgo8q/1/) As you will note, if you inspect the result part of it, you can see that it generates the name properly, but that name is produced on all new select options that are created.  How can I get that to dynamically change with what I currently have?

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.ad_inquiry_locations', function() {
    $(this).next('select, button').remove();
    var select = $('<select />', {'class' : 'ad_inquiry_locations', value:"", **name:"guest_al-2"**}); // In bold is where I am placing the name attribute for any dynamically created select box
    var option = $('<option />', {text : 'Add a location', disabled : 'disabled'});
    var button = $('<button />', {text : 'Remove Location', click : function() { 
        $(this).prev().remove() 
        if ( $('.ad_inquiry_locations').length == 1 ) $(this).remove();
    }});

    select.append(option, $('option:not(:selected):not(:first)', this).clone(true) );

    $(this).after( select );
    select.after(button);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- START OF ADDING LOCATIONS -->
<select id="select1" class="ad_inquiry_locations" value="" name="guest_pl" required>

    <option value="" selected disabled>Select primary location</option>
    <option value="Beloit">Beloit</option>
    <option value="Concordia">Concordia</option>
    <option value="Glen-Elder">Glen Elder</option>
    <option value="Jewell">Jewell</option>

</select>
<!-- END OF ADDING LOCATIONS -->
```

**PHP:** - (This part is on a separate file that sends these variables to me via email)

```
$primaryLocation = $_POST['guest_pl'];
$addLocation2 = $_POST['guest_al-2'];
$addLocation3 = $_POST['guest_al-3'];
$addLocation4 = $_POST['guest_al-4'];
```

Comment: what about this: `name: "guest_al-" + ($('.ad_inquiry_locations').length + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On option is by adding `var boxNumber = 2;` outside as a global and increment it every time a new `select` is appended. You can seed from any number you want.

```
    var boxNumber = 2;
    $(document).on('change', '.ad_inquiry_locations', function () {
        $(this).next('select, button').remove();
        var select = $('<select />', {
                'class' : 'ad_inquiry_locations',
                value : "",
                name : "guest_al-" + boxNumber      });
       ....//existing code
       .....
       boxNumber = boxNumber + 1;
        .....
    });


    var button = $('<button />', {
   text: 'Remove Location',
   click: function() {
  $(this).prev().remove()
  if ($('.ad_inquiry_locations').length == 1){ 
  $(this).remove();
  boxNumber = boxNumber-1; //decrements when removed :)
  }
 }
});
```

Output [image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Even if I change `boxNumber = 2+1;` The latter only changes the number to 3 at the end of each newly created select box name attr.

Comment: This is very close, however, if you remove any select box, but then end up adding another, that value continues to go up by 1.  Is there a way to change that where if a new select box was added, it would go up by 1, but if it was removed, it would go down by 1?

Comment: Updated answer to handle remove `select`.

Comment: Scratch that, I got it to work now.  I added `boxNumber = BoxNumber - 1;` to var button if statement and it seems to be working now.  Much appreciated on the help!

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I did - glad we are on the same page!  I'll mark your answer as correct!  Thanks again Searching